# Return type of this ternary operation? (other than any)

Tags: typescript

```
return (index === 0) ? undefined : {row: rows[index], index};
```

where row = ElementFinder and index = number

What would be the return type of this expression?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much any modern IDE would show it to you and I don't know what exactly are you trying achieve, but the return type of this will be `{row: ElementFinder, index: number} | undefined`.

There's really not much to explain here. It's either `undefined` if `index === 0` or an object which contains `index` field (and we know that it's a number) and you said `row` has type `ElementFinder`, so I'm assuming `rows` has type `ElementFinder[]`. Therefore the the other option is `{row: ElementFinder, index: number}`. So the effective type is the union of those two - `{row: ElementFinder, index: number} | undefined`.

There's one thing to keep in mind: type of `row` is `ElementFinder`, but it's very much possible that in runtime it will actually be `undefined`, because there's no check whether `row[index]` actually has any value assigned. TypeScript can't statically determine that, so if you want to be super safe you have to do that check manually. If we wanted to be super strict basically every array would have to be of type `Array<T | undefined>`, but I guess it's not the case because it would really complicate everything else. These are only my guesses, though.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.